# Remove prefix and suffix of page url in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I created controller using spring mvc:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {


@RequestMapping("/")

public String showHome() {

return  “/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp";

}



@RequestMapping(“/users")
    public String showUser() {
        return "/WEB-INF/pages/users.jsp";
}

}
```

I want to avoid writing this /WEB-INF/pages in each method and controller, is there any way to write only the name of jsp page (with folder or without), and the application returned the correct page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Spring MVC `InternalResourceViewResolver` by adding this in spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
```

and only return "home" in the controller

In your annotation-driven configuration the `InternalResourceViewResolver` should be set in the configuration class which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like such:

```
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```